# Get users from LDAP and authenticate in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, ldap

I have a SharePoint Online site, where users are in LDAP but not in SharePoint. How to get users from LDAP and connect to SharePoint Online site. I appreciate if  any one have any ideas on this and it would be great help if you know what can be done for authorisation after authentication through LDAP.

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: LDAP is not used in SharePoint Online. SharePoint Online leverages Azure AD instead. Thus, if you have a question regarding synchronizing between an on-prem LDAP system and Azure AD, it may be best to open this question up in Serverfault.

Comment: Came to know that there is something called DirSync to achieve this.

Comment: Our admin team raised a support ticket for this with Microsoft, they said that Microsoft are only supporting on-prem Active Directory sync using Azure AD Connect tool.

 Any inputs on this is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Santosh

Answer (score 0):

See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-integration-with-on-premises-environments-263faf8d-aa21-428b-aed3-2021837a4b65 for a more thorough description of what I've tried to describe here.

## Option 1 - Use Azure Active Directory Connect to sync your on-premise ADFS with Office 365 ADFS

You will need to set up a synchronization between your on-premise ADFS with the Azure ADFS that exists on Office 365.

- Before you sync, you need to set up your active directory such that it is compatible to be synced with an Azure Active Directory: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Prepare-to-provision-users-through-directory-synchronization-to-Office-365-01920974-9e6f-4331-a370-13aea4e82b3e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
- There is also a tool called IdFix that will identify problems that you have on your on-premise ADFS that will cause issues once you try to sync to the Azure ADFS https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-and-run-the-Office-365-IdFix-tool-f4bd2439-3e41-4169-99f6-3fabdfa326ac?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
- Set up AD Synchronization for Office 365: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-directory-synchronization-for-Office-365-1b3b5318-6977-42ed-b5c7-96fa74b08846
- Install Azure Active Directory Connect: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect

## Option 2 - Use a third party tool

You can also use a tool called Okta which I have not used but it sounds like it does a lot of the leg work for you: https://www.okta.com/office365/